# Data in GridView is not being displayed correctly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am displaying a datagridview using

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

When the dgv is displayed only the top left cell has a visible value. However when I click in other cells, the data in that cells becomes visible.

Any ideas why this could be happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way for binding is

```
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Your table name");
    conn.Close() ;
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Your table name";
```

If  this doesn't work please post more of your code.

Comment: `DataTable dt1;
dt1 = DtSet.Tables[0].Copy();
dt1.TableName = "tblFixed";
DtSet.Tables.Add(dt1);
//Create dataview to sort data
DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);
dv.Sort = "Number ASC, Serial No ASC, Open Date ASC";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;`

Comment: please try the general code i have given above(modify it as per your need).... if it still doesn't work please reply :-)

Comment: Using the datatable rather than the dataview as you suggested still has the same results. Which code do yo need to see?

Comment: Update - I tried running my code on a new project and it works fine, but I'd prefer not to start from scratch again if possible as I put a lot of work into the form. If anyone has any suggestions...?